# Static bitmap variables access between Fragments

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-asynctask, android-cardview

`ImageView`s in a `CardView` are not loading from an `LRUCache`. Am sure something is amiss, but unable to figure it out after days of debugging. If only the code could be presented here in entirety, but here are the most relevant snippets.

**The setup**
[image]

`TextViews`  in the `RecyclerView`s’  `CardView`s are binding perfectly, but not the `ImageView`s in the same `CardView`s. I am sure the images are present in the caches because, long click on the (blank) `ImageView`s do show the image in another `WebView`, as per the program. The statics of `Fragment1` load in an `AsyncTask` and `Fragment` 1 and 2 load *after* the `AsyncTask` completes.

**`CardView` Layout**

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/flDContainer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlDetFront"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvDet"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="12dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="2dp">

                   <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDsDistance"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDsDistanceUnit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="10sp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlMediaLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/DetMedia"
                    android:layout_width="310dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:maxHeight="200dp"
                    android:maxWidth="310dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/cake_12"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    :
    :
    :
    :
```

**`ViewPager` adapter**

```
class MyShopperPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    public MyShopperPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg)
    {
        if (arg == 0)
        {
            fragment = new Fragment1();
        }
        if (arg == 1)
        {
            fragment = new Fragment2();
        }
        if (arg == 2)
        {
            fragment = new Fragment3();
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        String pageTitle = "";

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                pageTitle = "TAB 1";
                break;
            case 1:
                pageTitle = "TAB 2";
                break;
            case 2:
                pageTitle = "TAB 3";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return pageTitle;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object)
    {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
} // of class MyShopperPagerAdapter
```

**`RecyclerView` adapter’s  `onBindViewHolder`**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyCardHolder myCardHolder, final int position)
{
    MyView my = this.mysView.get(position);

    String logoFilename = my.getMyerLogo();
    String address = my.getAddress();
    String city = my.getCity();
    String state = my.getState();
    String country = my.getCountry();
    String zip = my.getZip();
        :
        :
        :
    myCardHolder.shopSL.setText(my.getSubLocality());
    myCardHolder.myEndDate.setText(UIHelper.makeDisplayDate(Long.parseLong(myEnds), false));
        :
        :
        :
    Bitmap tempBitmap;
    tempBitmap = fragment1.logoMemCache.get(logoFilename);
    myCardHolder.shopLogo.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);
    tempBitmap = fragment1.myetMemCache.get(myFilename);
    myCardHolder.myet.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap);

    myCardHolder.tvAddress.setText(fullAddress);
    myCardHolder.tvPhones.setText(phones);
        :
        :
        :
}
```

**`ViewHolder`**

```
public class MyCardHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
private final String LOG_TAG = "POJO MyCardHolder";

RelativeLayout llMyCardFront;
RelativeLayout myTakenCounterLayout;
RelativeLayout myDateLayout;
TextView tvDistance;
TextView tvAddress;
TextView tvPhones;
TextView distanceUnit;
ImageView det;
TextView myTop;
TextView myBot;
ImageView shopLogo;
TextView shopName;
    :
    :
    :
// FAB toolbar
FloatingActionButton fabDirections, fabCallMobile, fabCallLandline, fabWebsite;

public MyCardHolder(View myItemView)
{
    super(myItemView);
    RelativeLayout myUserStatusLayout;

    llMyCardFront = (RelativeLayout) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.rlMyetFront);
    tvDistance = (TextView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMysDistance);
    claimButton = (Button) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.btMyClaim);
    distanceUnit = (TextView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMysDistanceUnit);
    det = (ImageView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.DetMedia);
    myTop = (TextView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.primaryTitle);
    myBot = (TextView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
    shopLogo = (ImageView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.shopLogo);
    shopName = (TextView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.shopName);
                    :
                    :
                    :
                    :
    fabDirections = (FloatingActionButton) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.fabDirections);
                    :
                    :
                    :
}
}
class MyTapListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
final String LOG_TAG = "MyTapListener";

@Override
public void onClick(View myItemView)
{
    CardView cardFront = (CardView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.cvMyet);
    CardView cardBack = (CardView) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.cvMyetBack);

    RelativeLayout llMyetBack = (RelativeLayout) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.rlMyetBack);
    RelativeLayout llMyetFront = (RelativeLayout) myItemView.findViewById(R.id.rlMyetFront);

    /* Some layout animations here when the user clicks on a CardView */
                    :
                    :
                    :
}
}
class FABToolbarListener implements View.OnClickListener
{

    /* FAB listener */
                    :
                    :
                    :
} // of class FABToolbarListener
class MyMediaListener implements View.OnLongClickListener
{
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View clickedPic)
{
    int id = clickedPic.getId();
    Context context = clickedPic.getContext();
    String filename = (String) clickedPic.getTag(id);
    String shopName = (String) clickedPic.getTag(R.id.action_show_website);
    showOriginalImage(context, picFilename, shopName);
    return false;
}

private void showOriginalImage(Context context, String filename, String shopName)
{
    Intent fullMyetIntent = new Intent(context, ZoomerActivity.class);
    fullDIntent.putExtra(MyContract.D_PREFIX, filename);
    fullDIntent.putExtra(MyContract.D_PICKED, shopName);
    context.startActivity(fullDIntent);
} // of showOriginalImage() }
```

**`CardView` output**

[image]

Is there any `CardView` - `ImageView` - `LRUCache` relationship or quirk or expert trick that I am missing here?

Please let me know what other code you will need to examine.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: where is your View Holder code ?

Comment: Thanks for looking in, @AllayKhalil! Please review the updated question - added the `ViewHolder` snippet.

Comment: Finally, had to just cook my own recipe. Here's what worked for me: 

 -Made the adapter class inner to the `Fragment`
 -Processed images into the `LRUCache` in an `AsyncTask`